# How to get my own Mysql Query work?

Tags: mysql

Can please someone tell me why this query is not working in MySQL....Or how to get it work?

```
UPDATE table1, table2 SET abc = 0 FROM table2 
WHERE table2.xyz > 0 AND table1.id_x = table2.id_x
```

Thank You

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what the error message says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want a `JOIN` in an `UPDATE`.  The correct syntax in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN
       table2
       ON table1.id_x = table2.id_x
    SET abc = 0 
    WHERE table2.xyz > 0;
```

Your query does not work for basically two reasons:

- MySQL does not support `FROM` in the `UPDATE` statement (although SQL Server and Postgres do).
- You have used `table1` without defining it.